# What built-in framework objects are available to controller's constructor in the Asp.Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-core, lifecycle

When I run my Asp.Net Core 1.1 MVC project, I can do things like this in my controller's constructor:

```
public MyController(
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings, 
    IHostingEnvironment environment, 
    ILogger<MyController> logger)
{
    ....
```

It works, but how is it getting there?  I know where I populated it in Startup.cs and put it in the DI/IoC, but I do not know what's going on here.  Why/How is it working the way it does?

This did not help,
[asp.net mvc what is the life of a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373331/asp-net-mvc-what-is-the-life-of-a-controller)

Comment: Go read up on dependency injection :)

Comment: I know what DI is.  I don't know how it is getting into the Controller.  Somewhere in the framework it "just works" using the IoC.

Comment: Those dependencies are being injected into the controller, what exactly don't you get?

Comment: I answered the question but I recommend simply downloading the sourcecode from GitHub and read though it. It will give you way more in depth insight in how things work.

Comment: @DavidG The How is what I did not get.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts at play here:

After the routes have defined which controller should be used. The `IControllerActivator` creates the controller. Aspnet Core contains a `ServiceBasedControllerActivator` which uses the `HttpContext.RequestServices` which is the `IServiceProvider` created in  the startup class.

The `IServiceProvider` is created from the IServiceColection:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<IMyInterface, MyClass>();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(); //ioc container
serviceProvider.GetService<IMyInterface>(); //will create an instance of: MyClass
```

The same way this `ServiceBasedControllerActivator` works: it checks which properties the constructor has and injects them from the `ServiceProvider`.